# ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Есть некий запрос

```
    with ids as (select jr.id
             from tesc3.journal_records jr, tesc3.journal_field_data jfd
             where jr.journal_id = 218
             and jr.edit_state = 0
             and jr.journal_table_id = 1001
             and jr.id = jfd.journal_record_id
             and jfd.field_name = 'PACK_NUM'
             and jfd.string_value in (select to_char(packet_number)
                                      from tesc3.muft_inspection
                                      where edit_state = 0
                                      and packet_number is not null
                                      and smelting = (select smelting
                                                      from tesc3.muft_inspection
                                                      where edit_state = 0 and packet_number = :PACKET)))
select distinct a1.order_num, a2.order_year
from                                                           
(select jfd1.journal_record_id, jfd1.string_value order_num
from tesc3.journal_field_data jfd1
where jfd1.field_name = 'MECH_NUM' 
and jfd1.journal_record_id in (select id
                               from ids )) a1
, (select jfd1.journal_record_id, jfd1.string_value  order_year
    from tesc3.journal_field_data jfd1
    where jfd1.field_name = 'MECH_YEAR' 
    and jfd1.journal_record_id in (select id
                                   from ids )) a2
where a1.journal_record_id = a2.journal_record_id
```

Который выбрасывает на сервере ошибку

> ORA-01427: подзапрос одиночной строки возвращает более одной строки

Но локально, у себя я выполняю этот запрос без ошибок

кто-то сталкивался с подобным?

UPD: в трассировке ругалось на запрос

```
with ids as (select jr.id
         from tesc3.journal_records jr, tesc3.journal_field_data jfd
         where jr.journal_id = 218
         and jr.edit_state = 0
         and jr.journal_table_id = 1001
         and jr.id = jfd.journal_record_id
         and jfd.field_name = 'PACK_NUM'
         and jfd.string_value in (select to_char(packet_number)
                                  from tesc3.muft_inspection
                                  where edit_state = 0
                                  and packet_number is not null
                                  and smelting = (select smelting
                                                  from tesc3.muft_inspection
                                                  where edit_state = 0 and packet_number = :PACKET)))
```

Comment: Как вы думаете, если я попробую выполнить ваш запрос, какую ошибку он выдаст?

Comment: @0xdb Думаю, что никакую !?

Comment: Ошибаетесь, вот такую: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: @0xdb простите, но это комментарий не по существу, понятное дело, что такой схемы БД у вас нет, но суть совсем не в этом

Comment: @Sosiska БД разные, данные разные. На одной БД какой то из подзапросов возвращает 1 строку и  все отлично. А на другой БД подзапрос находит более чем одну строку, при этом от него ожидается одиночный результат. Вот например если `select smelting
                                                      from tesc3.muft_inspection
                                                      where edit_state = 0 and packet_number = :PACKET` вернет более 1 строки, будет такая ошибка, потому что проверяется он на равенство. Так что 0xdb все верно говорит, не видя ваших данных точный ответ дать невозможно

Comment: @Mike этот подзапрос, который проверяет равенство, всегда возвращает одну строку, там не может быть 2 и более

Comment: А вы попробуйте его вызвать руками с теми параметрами что передаете в запрос с ошибкой и посмотрите. Я вот например других точек, способных выдать ошибку не вижу

Comment: Еще раз пересмотрел запрос и могу утверждать, что не смотря на то, что подзапрос, на который я указал выше, не может вернуть более 1 строки, он их все таки возвращает. А если вы так уверены что там ровно 1 строка, то попробуйте заменить = на in, хуже то не будет, если строка одна ...

Comment: @Mike Хм. звучит мудро и разумно, воспользуюсь вашим советом, спасибо